# How come files uploaded to S3 via URL have no extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip

I've got picture uploads working with s3 on heroku no problem.

I also have a method that enables users to upload from a web-address.

Unfortunately, it seems as though when pictures are uploaded using this method they are saved without their file extension.

So I get this sort of link for image urls...

> http://s3.amazonaws.com/mysite/images/23/original.?1311799466

If the same image had been uploaded locally it would look like this:

> http://s3.amazonaws.com/mysite/images/23/original.**JPG**?1311799466

In my `pic` model this is the code I'm using to allow uploads via web addresses:

```
def download_remote_image

        begin
            self.image = open(URI.parse(self.pic_url))
        rescue
            errors.add_to_base("- something is wrong with the image url.")
            return false
        else
            return true
        end
    end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what's an example of pic_url? also the uploader you are using might need other custom attributes on the File class that usually are injected in a custom module.

Comment: pic_url would be a string like: "http://randsco.com/_miscPgs/cssZoom03.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

Change with this:

```
def download_remote_image
  begin
    io = open(URI.parse(pic_url))
    def io.original_filename; base_uri.path.split('/').last; end
    io.original_filename.blank? ? nil : io
  rescue
  end
end
```

Careful, recent versions of Paperclip throw errors when encountering a io object instead of File, not sure if they fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using paperclip the picture url should be generated with paperclip such as:

```
self.image(:thumb)
```